# REST endpoint and gRPC backend

Tags: rest, go, grpc

I am writing a REST server in Go. The server need to communicate to other gRPC server. The REST server will now also function as gRPC server/client also. What is the suggested way to achieve this ?

Comment: What is the question? Just run and communicate :)

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky I have my sample code here: https://play.golang.org/p/Ack83hLV09  . Check L30 I need to run gRPC server as goroutine and http server in main. What I am asking is, is this the correct way to do it ? Or is there any other better way ?

Comment: If they do not conflict and use different ports that’s ok.